# Geometry question on triangles within a convex quadrilateral from 1990 BMO1

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

I am preparing for BMO1 this year and found an old BMO1 paper from 1990 with this geometry question.

> The diagonals of a convex quadrilateral ABCD intersect at O. The centroids of triangles AOD and BOC are P and Q; the orthocentres of triangles AOB and COD are R and S. Prove that PQ is perpendicular to RS.

After drawing out the diagram I can see a lot of cyclic quadrilaterals, and it looks like in the process of finding the orthocentres R and S, we have found the orthocentres of AOD and BOC too. I can't really find anywhere to start though, please could someone give me a hint on how to start solving this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the figure below, we just need to show that $RS$ is perpendicular to $KL$, where $K$ and $L$ are the midpoints of $AD$ and $BC$, respectively (notice that $PQ$ is parallel to $KL$). Now, we place the quadrilateral on the coordinate system such that $O=(0,0)$, and the slopes of the lines $BD$ and $AC$ are $a$ and $b$, respectively. In this manner, WLOG, we assume $A=(m,bm)$, $B=(t,at)$, $D=(s,as)$, and $C=(n,bn)$.
[image]

Now we can easily compute $R$, which is the intersection of the two lines (in fact, two of the altitudes of $\triangle AOB$) as below:
$$y-bm=\frac{-1}{a}(x-m),
\\
y-at=\frac{-1}{b}(x-t).$$

Hence;
$$R=(\frac{(ab+1)(at-bm)}{a-b},\frac{(ab+1)(m-t)}{a-b}).$$

This immediately gives the fact that we must have (because the corresponding equations are exactly the same):

$$S=(\frac{(ab+1)(as-bn)}{a-b},\frac{(ab+1)(n-s)}{a-b}).$$

Therefore, the slope of the line passing through $RS$ is:

$$\frac{(n-s)-(m-t)}{(as-bn)-(at-bm)}.$$

Now, note that:

$$K=(\frac{m+s}{2}, \frac{as+bm}{2}), \\ L=(\frac{t+n}{2}, \frac{at+bn}{2}).$$

So, the slope of the line passing through $KL$ is:
$$\frac{(at+bn)-(as+bm)}{(t+n)-(m+s)}.$$

Now that we have the slopes, it is almost obvious that $RS$ is perpendicular to $KL.$

We are done.

Comment: Thanks for answering, how did you get that PQ is parallel to KL? also, do you think there's a solution that doesn't use coordinate geometry?

Comment: @ChrisDaniel You're welcome. Note that the centroids lie on $OK$ and $OL$, dividing the lines in ratio $2:1$, which means $PQ$ must be parallel to $KL$ (Thales's theorem). I am almost sure there is a geometric solution to this problem, which probably uses the fact that $PQ$ and $KL$ are parallel.

Comment: ohh I see now, Thanks once again, I'm going to try finding a geometric solution using that fact now